# Karaf works with spring camel routes but not with java DSL camel routes

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-karaf, smpp, blueprint-osgi

I developed a project that uses camel smpp routes in karaf.
In the beginning I used spring to write my camel routes. That worked fine.
Later I tried to use java DSL to write the camel smpp routes but everything I have done, results to this.

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[smpp://username@localhost:2775?pa... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: smpp://username@localhost:2775?password=apassword due to: No component found with scheme: smpp

Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint:   smpp://username@localhost:2775?password=apassword due to: No component found with scheme: smpp
```

I have even tried blueprint to call the bean that creates the java DSL camel routes but keep getting the above.

from karaf console:

```
karaf@root> list | grep smpp
[ 171] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: jsmpp (2.1.0.4)
[ 172] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-smpp (2.11.0)
karaf@root> features:list | grep smpp
[installed  ] [2.11.0         ] camel-smpp                              camel-2.11.0
```

What I am trying to call is this snippet from a bean either in spring or blueprint:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
        fromF("smpp://%s@%s:%s?password=%s", username, destination, port, password)
        .bean(new SmsReceiver(), "printPdus");
    }
});             
context.start();
```

What should I do to make the java DSL smpp route work? Why does smpp route in spring works but java DSL smpp doesn't? What should I install or search for?

Answer (score 0):

See this page http://camel.apache.org/spring at the section *Using Java Code* how to from the spring xml file to refer to a < bean > which is the Java RouteBuilder class. That is the way to have it work in OSGi.

Comment: Your solution worked but doesn't solve my problem which is the creation of an smpp camel route with a uri that derives from an sql camel route. I call in a configure() the route from("sql:select username,password from accounts?dataSource=dataSource").bean(ReceiverBean, "buildConsumers"); for a <routeBuilder> bean which runs but the pollingConsumer's exchange=consumer.receive("smpp://...); in buildConsumers() throws Failed to resolve endpoint:smpp://... due to:No component found with scheme: smpp again because i think the consumer is not properly instantiated because of wrong context.

Comment: As told on the Camel mailing list you are doing it wrong, when you manually create CamelContext and whatnot. Initializing Camel to run in OSGi is not easy. Do as the link above tells you to have it work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are using camel context directly and you add route to context instance (created how?). If you create DefaultCamelContext instance then you need to configure specific component resolver (see org.apache.camel.core.osgi.OsgiComponentResolver).